# Extended ASCII in Zebra Printer C#

Tags: c#, zebra-printers

I am writing a program in C# to print custom cards with a Zebra ZXP 3. I am using Zebra SDK. When I try to print letter Ñ (in spanish), the printer prints a question mark.

I am sure that it is an encoding issue.

This was my original code:

```
var graphics = new ZBRGraphics();

graphics.DrawText(10, 10, graphics.AsciiEncoder.GetBytes(text), 
graphics.AsciiEncoder.GetBytes(font), fontSize, fontStyle, textColor, out 
error);
```

When I inspect the value of "graphics.AsciiEncoder.GetBytes(text)" I see a **63** in Ñ position.

63 is the question mark ASCII code. So I tried:

```
var e = Encoding.GetEncoding("CP437");

e.GetBytes(text) //Replacing graphics.AsciiEncoder.GetBytes(text)
```

In that way, when I inspect, the Ñ is translated as a **165**. This is the correct ASCII Extended value. But this way, the printer prints **¥**.

Comment: Don't use ASCII encoding? From what I can tell, ZBRGDIDrawText takes a byte array containing the text. Try using Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes to get the bytes of the text and use that. If that doesn't work, check with them to see what encodings they support.

Comment: The ¥ character has decimal value 165 in unicode. Try UTF-8.

Comment: https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SA293&pmv=print&impressions=false

Comment: Note that there's no such character encoding as "extended ASCII". There are *many* 1-byte encodings which have the same values as ASCII for 0-127. Be very wary of any site which talks about "extended ASCII".

Comment: Thanks very much for all the answers. I will try them and then I tell you the results.

Comment: @HHLV UTF-8 encodes ¥ as 0xC2 0xA5 (two 8-bit code units). The link to the Zebra SDK shows that it uses UTF-16 (`Encoding.Unicode`), which does encode ¥ as 165 (one 16-bit code unit).

Answer (score 0):

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text); //Generates two bytes for Ñ. In decimal, they are: 195 and 145.

Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text); //Generates 209 for Ñ, but it puts a zero byte after each byte with value.
```

The aproach I went for was:

```
var e = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
e.GetBytes(text);
```

Because it generates only a byte which decimal value is **209**. It works well.

My client has the printer, so all the tests I did were in the code. So maybe, some (or all) of the proposed answers work too.

Thanks everyone for your time.